# I've done it before, but now it gives me errors

Tags: arrays

I wanted to compile this, but I had difficulty.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item\[\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\land q\\
  & p\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & q
  \end{array}\]
 \item\[\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\rightarrow q\\
  & q\rightarrow r\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & p\rightarrow r
  \end{array}\]
  \item\[\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & p\lor q
  \end{array}\] 
% \item\[\begin{array}{rl}
  %& p\lor q\\
  %& p\rightarrow r\\
 % & q\rightarrow s\\\arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
 %\therefore & r\lor s
 % \end{array}/] 
 %\item[]Simplificaci\'on\\
 %\item[]Silogismo Hipot\'etico\\
 %\item[]Ley de adici\'on\\
% \item[]Silogismo Disyuntivo
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{multicols}
```

Comment: David said in other topic that you have to change order of commands `\arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}`.

Comment: For the code to be written correctly, click on the brace button `{}`

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Please help us to help you by including the preamble needed and the `\begin{document}\end{dociment}` commands to the code given.

Comment: I have all the necessary packages in the preamble. Maybe I have not given myself to understand well, just do not compile what I have commented. Everything else is fine

Comment: We don't... and may be have not the time or the will to search for them... (Just trying to explain some rules of this community in order to get easier help from us. I mean that if you are not willing to provide us the full code needed to make the tests, we possibly will not find the will to search for the packages needed too)

Comment: You can verify that everything compiles well, except the fourth item.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: `\end{array}/] ` looks wrong. Try `\end{array}\]` instead.

Comment: I was able to solve it.

Comment: @CarlosFeliz... I didn't even tried to help about your problem, I did try to help you to understand some rules of the community (this one and most such "communities") in order to get easier help with this or future problems. After my mesage I read it and "heard" it somehow aggressive... And because of hearing it like this (that was not something I felt or done like this) I edited immediately my comment to explain what I meant. With the same way, I am adding now that it would be nice from you to add an answer of what you done to solve your problem in order to help future users...

Comment: In such communities, when I (or someone) trying to help solve a problem someone else, doesn't really doing this to help just one user but to help the community have "nice documented solutions" in several problems on LaTeX here and this way we help LaTeX development and "spreading" because most of us really love LaTeX and its features, so, would like to help the community of LaTeX and not just one member to solve a problem. We also don't wan't to help in private messages (at least if these messages or the solution that we will find through them will never be available for the community)

Comment: is this a repeat of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456147/trabajando-con-el-entorno-array (it contains the same error example code) please do not post multiple times, you can edit the question to add new details.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like the following, rather than try to get manual alignment with two column format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\deduction}[2][10em]{%
  \makebox[#1][l]{$\begin{array}[t]{rl@{}}#2\end{array}$}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\arrayrulecolor{red}

 \item
   \deduction{
     & p\land q\\
     & p\\
     \cline{2-2}
     \therefore & q
   }
   Simplificación

 \item
   \deduction{
     & p\rightarrow q\\
     & q\rightarrow r\\
     \cline{2-2}
     \therefore & p\rightarrow r
  }
  Silogismo Hipot\'etico

  \item
    \deduction{
       & p\\
       \cline{2-2}
       \therefore & p\lor q
    }
    Ley de adici\'on

 \item
   \deduction{
     & p\lor q\\
     & p\rightarrow r\\
     & q\rightarrow s\\
     \cline{2-2}
     \therefore & r\lor s
  }
  Silogismo Disyuntivo

\arrayrulecolor{black}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\arrayrulecolor` is a *global* declaration, so it's useless to repeat it every time, but the normal color should be restored back, unless you want all of your `array` and `tabular` rules be red.

I added a new command for the convenience of not having to repeat the same code over and over.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your help has really been useful. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth item I could solve by changing it

from:

```
\[\begin{array}

\end{array}\]
```

to

```
$\begin{array}

\end{array}$
```

Actually, I do not know why he was giving me errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow, array} % para las tablas
\usepackage{float} % para usar [H]

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item[]\[\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\land q\\
  & p\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & q
  \end{array}\]
 \item[]\[\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\rightarrow q\\
  & q\rightarrow r\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & p\rightarrow r
  \end{array}\]
  \item[]\[\begin{array}{ll}
  & p\\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
  \therefore & p\lor q
  \end{array}\]
  \item[]$\begin{array}{rl}
  & p\lor q \\
  & p\rightarrow r \\
  & q\rightarrow s \\
  \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-2}
 \therefore & r\lor s
  \end{array}$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `enumerate` if you are going to use items with no labels and with displayed math contents.